# Report framework for Angular 6

Tags: angular, obiee, oracle-bi

I need to integrate Oracle BI (Oracle business Intelligence) reports with 
Angular 6.

Does Angular 6 supports this integration or Any other reporting framework which should be used for integration with Angular 6 framework?

Comment: Hi. Your question is extremely vague and you're talking about 2 completely different technologies and talking about integrating them together. Maybe give some example or scenario of what you're trying to achieve then rephrase, e.g. "Using a reporting framework to display data from Oracle BI in Angular 6".

Comment: My use case is as follows : 1. I have a report developed using Oracle BI tool. 2.On click of generate report button in the screen which is developed using Angular 6, i want to open this report.  Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying any pertinent information like version, host OS or the likes, so the best that can be done is post the link to the OBI Integrator's Guide and suggest you read it and comprehend what URL integration does and how it works.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIEIT/toc.htm

We are not sitting in front of your screen nor are we inside your head so we can not know what "click of generate report button" does or requires or literally anything at all.

The worse you describe your issue, the harder it is to actually help you. You have to out a minimum of effort into explaining your issue.